# Database calls fail after session timeout

Tags: sql, asp.net, session, web-config

I have a Webforms page that uses ADO.net to make database calls.  When the user leaves the page idle for a while, then tries to save, the call to the database fails.  He has to refresh for it to work.

**My question**: In .NET Webforms, is there some kind of a session timeout that would make calls to the database fail?  Is there a timeout property I need to set in the web.config?  Or could it be an IIS thing?

Comment: Are you opening and closing the connection for each DB operation?

Comment: You really need to show your code.  Most likely you aren't opening/closing the DB connection every time you are making a call to that database.  If you are storing the DB connection info in session state then you are doing it wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Session will typically expire after 20 minutes by default and therefore any reference to Session will return null values. If you're not checking for null before accessing the values you'll get Null Reference exceptions.

If your form's button click event is not accessing anything within the Session object than you shouldn't have a problem.

Answer (score 0):

it's a little difficulty to give you a good answer without seeing anything of your code. But I'll try to give you some tips:

**1)** When a session times out, the application obviously will lose access to user's stored values on the session, so, if you are using the user session to store the database connection, connection string or something similar, yes, the database connection will be affected.

**2)** Session and Authentication are different things and have different treatment, for example, you can have one of them expired while the other one is active, your code needs to take care of both situations.

**3)** Yes, you can increase session timeout by changing the below settings on web.config, but try to not store anything related to database connection on Sessions, the best is to avoid using of them, but if you need, try to put small and simple pieces of information inside them.

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <sessionState mode="StateServer" timeout="30" />
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```